# R lubridate: pretty_dates fails for some input data

Tags: r, lubridate

I am having trouble using lubridate's `pretty_dates` function. It fails in some cases:

```
library(lubridate)

datetimes <- structure(c(1391640346, 1393856900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")
pretty_dates(datetimes, 10)
```

(I normally wouldn't construct datetimes like this, it's just what `dput` gave me.)
This fails with error message:

```
Error in seq.POSIXt(start, end, paste(binlength, binunits)) : 'to' must be of length 1
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

I am using `lubridate_1.3.3`, the latest version from CRAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that looks like a bug. It seems to only be a problem when you have a POSIX object that has a time other than midnight and a prefered units of "days". You can re-create with other values with

```
pretty_dates(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2014-02-05 01:00:00 GMT"), 
    by = "5 day", length.out = 2), 2)
```

while something like

```
pretty_dates(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2014-02-05 01:00:00 GMT"), 
    by = "9 hours", length.out = 2), 2)
```

or

```
pretty_dates(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2014-02-05 01:00:00 GMT"), 
    by = "3 months", length.out = 2), 2)
```

work.

Looks like you can work around it with

```
pretty_dates(as.Date(datetimes),10)
```

Comment: The error stems from this line of `pretty_dates` - `end <- pretty.point(max(rng), binunits, binlength, start = FALSE)`. If you remove `start=FALSE` it all works just fine.

Comment: Well, at that point it's running `pretty.point(max(datetimes), "day", 2, start=F)`. And again `pretty.point(as.Date(max(datetimes)), "day", 2, start=F)` works. I think it has to do with the `ceiling_date` and `floor_date` in `pretty.point` which return different days when there is a time, and the same day when you do `as.Date` to remove the time. This messes with the `seq` that's called afterward.

Comment: `pretty.point(max(datetimes), "day", 2, start=F)` gives `character(0)` for me, which ruins the `seq` call.

Comment: The lubridate bug tracker is here: https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues, if you want to report this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The workaround takes away from pretty_dates otherwise excellent flexibility, for example when the interval is actually within a certain hour of a single day.
I reported it as a bug https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/248